# How to set LIstView with multiple arrays/strings?

Tags: android, arrays, eclipse, listview, android-intent

this is my code

I would like to add this method However, I would avoid them appearing the same url with every button click

so I'd like for each button clicked would change the url to display

I want to add this code

```
     mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 1)
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondaActivity.class);
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("URL")));
            }
                else if (position == 2)
                {Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondaActivity.class);
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("URL")));
```

Activity A

```
ArrayList<String> bottone;
Button b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //creazione fullscreen activity
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.gruppipuntate_activity);

    //rimozione action bar
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11){
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        b1 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button2);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button3);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button4);
        b5 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button5);
        b6 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button6);
        b7 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button7);
        b8 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button8);
        b9 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button9);
        b10 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button10);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        b3.setOnClickListener(this);
        b4.setOnClickListener(this);
        b5.setOnClickListener(this);
        b6.setOnClickListener(this);
        b7.setOnClickListener(this);
        b8.setOnClickListener(this);
        b9.setOnClickListener(this);
        b10.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

 }
    //gestione Switch java per selezione puntate
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String[] Product;

        Intent episodi = new Intent(GruppiPuntateActivity.this, EpisodiActivity.class);

         switch(v.getId()){ 
         case R.id.button1:
             Product = new String[]{"ciao", "1", "bottone"};
             episodi.putExtra("Product", Product);
             startActivity(episodi);
             break;
         case R.id.button2:
             Product = new String[]{"ciao", "2", "bottone"};
             episodi.putExtra("Product", Product);
             startActivity(episodi);
             break;
         case R.id.button3:
             Product = new String[]{"ciao", "3", "bottone"};
             episodi.putExtra("Product", Product);
             startActivity(episodi);
             break;
         case R.id.button4:
             Product = new String[]{"asd", "seco", "tezo"};
             episodi.putExtra("Product", Product);
             startActivity(episodi);
              break;
         case R.id.button5:
             Product = new String[]{"primo", "secondo", "terzo"};
             episodi.putExtra("Product", Product);
             startActivity(episodi);
              break;
         case R.id.button6:
             Product = new String[]{"primo", "secondo", "terzo"};
             episodi.putExtra("Product", Product);
             startActivity(episodi);
              break;
         case R.id.button7:
             Product = new String[]{"primo", "secondo", "terzo"};
             episodi.putExtra("Product", Product);
             startActivity(episodi);
              break;
         case R.id.button8:
             Product = new String[]{"primo", "secondo", "terzo"};
             episodi.putExtra("Product", Product);
             startActivity(episodi);
              break;
         case R.id.button9:
             Product = new String[]{"primo", "secondo", "terzo"};
             episodi.putExtra("Product", Product);
             startActivity(episodi);
              break;
         case R.id.button10:
             Product = new String[]{"primo", "secondo", "terzo"};
             episodi.putExtra("Product", Product);
             startActivity(episodi);
              break;
         }
    }
```

ACtivity B

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //creazione fullscreen activity
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.episodi_activity);

    final ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    String[] PP = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("Product"); 

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, PP);
    mylist.setAdapter(adapter);


mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
        if (position == 1)
        {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EpisodiActivity.class);
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1zfa4i_camera-cafe-3-stagione-ep-240-crema-miracolosa_shortfilms")));

        }
    }
});
```

}
}

Comment: Is your issue solved? Please don't forget to up vote and accept the answers which were most helpful to you.

Comment: Dob't worry now I try your code and then you vote if it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a new class which holds the data about each item in the `ListView` like this:

```
public class ViewModel {
    private String url;
    private String name;

    public ViewModel(String url, String name) {
        this.url = url;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return this.url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

The value returned by `toString()` is what is displayed in the `ListView`! To use this `ViewModel` class in an `ArrayAdapter` you have to do this:

```
// First we create the ViewModels for all the items in the ListView
ViewModel first = new ViewModel("first", "http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1zfa4i_camera-cafe-3-stagione-ep-240-crema-miracolosa_shortfilms");
ViewModel second = new ViewModel("second", "http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1zfarh_camera-cafe-3-stagione-ep-241-fuori-di-casa_shortfilms");
ViewModel third = new ViewModel("third", "http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1zfbes_camera-cafe-3-stagione-ep-242-la-mamma-di-pippo_shortfilms");

// Then we put all the items in a List
List<ViewModel> models = Arrays.asList(first, second, third);

// And finally create an ArrayAdapter which accepts those items
ArrayAdapter<ViewModel> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ViewModel>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, models);
mylist.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And then you can implement the `OnItemClickListener` like this:

```
mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {

        // We get the ViewModel at the clicked position and get its url
        ViewModel model = (ViewModel) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
        String url = model.getUrl();

        // And then we start the next Activity with the correct url
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EpisodiActivity.class);
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
    }
});
```

---

You can easily apply this to your code like this:

In `Activity` A you first have to put the urls you want to open with each list item in a `String[]` and pass that too along to `Activity` B:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String[] Product;
    String[] urls;

    Intent episodi = new Intent(GruppiPuntateActivity.this, EpisodiActivity.class);

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            Product = new String[]{"ciao", "1", "bottone"};
            urls = new String[] {"url1, url2, url3"};
            episodi.putExtra("Product", Product);
            episodi.putExtra("urls", urls);
            startActivity(episodi);
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            Product = new String[]{"ciao", "2", "bottone"};
            urls = new String[] {"url4, url5, url6"};
            episodi.putExtra("Product", Product);
            episodi.putExtra("urls", urls);
            startActivity(episodi);
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

And in `Activity` B you have to read both the product names and urls and then create a `ViewModel` for each item which is supposed to be displayed:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    // We get all the information we need, names and urls
    String[] products = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("Product");
    String[] urls = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("urls");

    // And in this loop we create the ViewModel instances from 
    // the name and url and add them all to a List
    List<ViewModel> models = new ArrayList<ViewModel>();
    for (int i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        String name = products[i];
        String url = urls[i];
        ViewModel model = new ViewModel(name, url);
        models.add(model);
    }

    // Here we create the ArrayAdapter and assign it to the ListView
    // We pass the List of ViewModel instances into the ArrayAdapter
    final ArrayAdapter<ViewModel> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ViewModel>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, models);
    mylist.setAdapter(adapter);

    mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {

            // Here we get the ViewModel at the given position
            ViewModel model = (ViewModel) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);

            // And the url from the ViewModel
            String url = model.getUrl();

            // Then we start the other Activity with the correct url
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EpisodiActivity.class);
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        }
    });
}
```

And that is pretty much it! If you have any other questions please feel free to ask!

Comment: so I'll just copy the code you just wrote and paste it?

Comment: Basically yes, why? You need to fill in all the missing information of course. My original answer was basically finished. All I did now is demonstrate how you would apply it.

Comment: ok thank you I have just one last question. 
gives me an error ViewModel as fix this?

Comment: The last part of your comment isn't even a sentence. No idea what you mean.

Comment: Sorry. the code that I inserted the Activity B shows me an error on the written ViewModel how can I fix it?

Comment: And you think that when you say "an error" that I magically know what you are talking about?

Comment: :) eclipse tells me: Multiple markers at this line 
- ViewModel can not be resolved 
to a type 
- ViewModel can not be resolved 
to a type

Comment: Have you copied the code of the `ViewModel` class? If you have it in an extra file you need the correct imports, but you can just copy and paste it directly into `Activity` B.

Comment: I do not understand where you must copy the code :) you have teamviewer?

Comment: Just copy it directly into `Activity` B. I am not gonna start a TeamViewer session with you. You know one should have learned programming before attempting to write an app.

Comment: I have only one problem. gives me the following error on mylist (mylist can not be resolved)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to understand what you are trying to do but I'm guessing what you want to do is change the URL to display in Activity B based on which button is clicked in Activity A. What you could do is add another called to putExtra in each button case. This extra would be the URL in string form and you would use getStringExtra in activity B to get again. A better explanation of your problem or goal would help.

Comment: well you guessed my intent 
can you show me with a few lines of code?